# Does $1 + \frac{1}{x} + \sqrt{\frac{2x}{x + 1}},$ have a global minimum?

Tags: calculus, inequality, computational-algebra, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Does the following function have a global minimum:

$$1 + \frac{1}{x} + \sqrt{\frac{2x}{x + 1}},$$

where $x \in \mathbb{N}$?

I tried using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+1+%2B+%281%2Fq%29+%2B+sqrt%282q%2F%28q+%2B+1%29%29), but it appears to give an inconsistent result.

Comment: Hint: the derivative of your expression is strictly less than $0$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Indeed, when I double-checked (again using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D[1+%2B+%281%2Fq%29+%2B+sqrt%282q%2F%28q+%2B+1%29%29]+%3C+0)), I do get a negative derivative for $x > 0$.  Thanks @Daryl!  Can you include more details to your comment and write it out as a complete answer so that I may be able to accept it?

Comment: I apologize @Daryl, but [Abhra Abir Kundu](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/48639/abhra-abir-kundu) was the first to give a complete (and comprehensive) answer to my question.  If only I could accept two different answers, I would.  But I will be accepting Abhra Abir Kundu's answer for now.

Comment: @ArnieBDris That's fine. This solution is probably more complete than mine. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1 + \frac{1}{x} + \sqrt{\frac{2x}{x + 1}}$$

$$=1 + \frac{1}{x} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{1 + \frac{1}{x}}}$$

$$=1 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{1 + \frac{1}{x}}}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{1 + \frac{1}{x}}}$$

Applying A.M. G.M. we have,

$$1 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{1 + \frac{1}{x}}}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{1 + \frac{1}{x}}}\geq3.((1 + \frac{1}{x})(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{1 + \frac{1}{x}}})^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

$$3.((1 + \frac{1}{x})(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{1 + \frac{1}{x}}})^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}=3.(\frac{1}{2})^{1/3}$$

Equality holds when $\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{1 + \frac{1}{x}}}$

Squaring both sides we get,

$$(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{3}=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\Rightarrow 1 + \frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{2^{1/3}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2^{1/3}}-1=\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\Rightarrow x=\frac{2^{1/3}}{1-2^{1/3}}$$

Now check the two nearest integers to x and compare the values of the expression at those values and the min. will global minimum .

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of the expression is
$$
\frac{1}{x(x+1)}\sqrt{\frac{x}{2(x+1)}}-\frac{1}{x^2},
$$
which is strictly negative for $x>0$. Hence, the function is always decreasing.

When $x<-1$, you can show that the derivative is zero at $x=-2-\sqrt[3]{2}-2^{2/3}\approx -4.84732$. See WolframAlpha [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+1+%2B+%281%2Fq%29+%2B+sqrt%282q%2F%28q+%2B+1%29%29&x=0&y=0) and [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=local+minima+1+%2B+%281%2Fq%29+%2B+sqrt%282q%2F%28q+%2B+1%29%29&x=0&y=0).

Thus, a local minima occurs at $x=-4$ or $x=-5$. There is no local minima for $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function

$$f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x} + \sqrt{\frac{2x}{x + 1}}$$

is always decreasing (as pointed out by [Daryl](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/36034)),
we have

$$f(x) > \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{f(x)} = 1 + \sqrt{2}.$$